# Show operator is well-defined

Tags: real-analysis

I'm given the following dilation operator

$$D:L^{p}\rightarrow L^{p},\ (Df)(x):=2^{1/2}f(2x),$$

and I have to show that it is well-defined. Here's where I've gotten so far:

For an arbitrary function $f\in L^{p}$ I know that

$$||f||_{p}=\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|^{p}\ \text{d}x\ \right)^{1/p}<\infty$$

So then I considered the norm of $(Df)(x)$:

$$||Df||_{p}=\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|2^{1/2}f(2x)|^{p}\ \text{d}x\ \right)^{1/p}=\left(2^{p/2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(2x)|^{p}\ \text{d}x\ \right)^{1/p}$$

But now I'm kinda stuck. My aim is to somehow be able to construct an inequality involving the norm of $f$, $||f||_{p}$, since this would be an argument that the operator is well-defined.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like $f \in L^p$ so

$$||Df(x)||_{p}=||2^{\frac{1}{2}} f(2x)||_{p}=\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|2^{1/2}f(2x)|^{p}\ \text{d}x\ \right)^{1/p}=\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|2^{1/2}f(2x)|^{p}\ \frac{1}{2} \text{d}(2x)\ \right)^{1/p}=\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|2^{1/2}f(x)|^{p}\ \frac{1}{2} \text{d}x\ \right)^{1/p}= 2^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{p}}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|^{p}\  \text{d}x\ \right)^{1/p}<\infty$$

Does this help ?

Comment: I'm not sure how you get from $\text{d}x$ to $\frac{1}{2}\text{d}(2x)$ and then to the next integral where $f(2x)$ is now $f(x)$?

Comment: it was by the substitution $2x=y$ so $dy=2dx$ and the limits stay the same

Comment: Ahhhhhh, now I see, that substitution makes a lot of sense!

Comment: Doesn't that also tell you that the operator norm is $||D||_{p}=2^{1/2-1/p}$?

Comment: yes, thats by definition obviously!

Comment: can you upvote the answer please

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help! I forgot to upvote the answer, but now I have!

Comment: But wait, how do yoy exactly get $2^{1/2-1/p}$?

Comment: Wait, I think I see why. The $2^{1/2}$ inside the absolute value just becomes $2^{1/2}$ since it's raised to the power $p$ and then to the power $1/p$. And then you take the factor $1/2$ inside the integral and raise it to the power $p$ and then simplify?